# SELECT from multiple tables where php variable equals a column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php variable that equals the value of a telephone number.

i want to be able to select from multiple tables where a column equal that variable

Whats the best way to do this, i tried something like:

```
//first select the company
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from customer where phone = :phone ");
$stmt->execute(array(':phone' => $res));
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($records) > 0) {
    $caller = $records[0]["company"];
}
elseif(count($records) == 0) {
    //otherwise check contacts
    $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from contacts where phone = :phone or mobile = :mobile ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':phone' => $res, ':mobile' => $res));
    $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $caller = $records[0]["forename"];
}
```

but thought it may be better to use something like a join or union?

Comment: The best way is to design your database so that you can run only one query with a given phone number.

Answer (score 0):

If you only selecting the telephone number that you want from each table you can put them into a single table using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

So something like this as MySQL (you can convert it to PHP)

```
(SELECT phone_number FROM t1 WHERE company = $yourvariable)
UNION
(SELECT phone_number FROM t2 WHERE phone_number = $yourvariable)
```

Comment: can i then return my results using phone_number ?

Comment: or do something like, select phone as tel and select phone as tel, mobile as tel then return tel